# Not able to loop through returned data from api

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have data being returned from an api, and I am taking that data and pushing it into an array, if i console.log the array with the data from the api it shows up, however, when I try to loop through the array but there is nothing in it, but as I mentioned earlier, I can console log the array and there's data in it.

My code is..

```
(()=>{
    let zips = ["98439", "90210", "18614", "98459", "85331", "30028", "17584", "12345", "34983", "48503", "934399", "17088", "94874", "93893", "23939", "34989", "79843", "34398", "03438", "93843", "34893", "43893", "90834", "93439", "17876"];
    let coordResults = [];

    for(let i = 0; i< zips.length; i++){
        fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + zips[i]+ "&key=" + GoogleAPIKEY + "")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        coordResults.push(data.results[0].address_components);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Do something for an error here
      });
    }

    console.log(coordResults);

    for(let j = 0; j < coordResults.length; j++){
        console.log(coordResults);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `console.log(coordResults);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how promise works, your data isn't available instantly, for that reason `for` loop doesn't see your data

Here's proper solution

```
(()=>{
    let zips = ["98439", "90210", "18614", "98459", "85331", "30028", "17584", "12345", "34983", "48503", "934399", "17088", "94874", "93893", "23939", "34989", "79843", "34398", "03438", "93843", "34893", "43893", "90834", "93439", "17876"];
    let coordResults = [];

    for(let i = 0; i< zips.length; i++){
        // attach to variable
        const promise = fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + zips[i]+ "&key=" + GoogleAPIKEY + "")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        return data.results[0].address_components // return your proper field
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Do something for an error here
      });

      // push promise to array, not data
      coordResults.push(promise)
    }

    console.log(coordResults); // this is list of promises, await them
    Promise
      .all(coordResults) // wait them all
      .then((results) => { // here's your list of items
        for(let j = 0; j < results.length; j++){
            const data = results[j];
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `coordResults` array starts empty, then after you receive the result back from the fetch, it has several results pushed into it.

However, when you are looping through it, that is happening outside of the context of the asyncronous (fetch), so it is still empty at that point.

The reason the console log shows it as *not* being empty is because console.log is not static. If you output an object, and that object later gets updated, so does the console.log output. It's misleading, but that's how it works.

If you move your second for loop up into the `.then()` chain, you'll see it output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are loggin the array **before** you have waited for the `fetch` request to be finished. So your array will always be empty at that point in time.

What you should do is use the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the `zips` array and return the `fetch` result in a new array. The `zipFetches` will be an array of promises. Each promise is the result of the fetch request.

Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all of the promises in `zipFetches` to be finished and then show the result in the console.

```
let zips = ["98439", "90210", "18614", "98459", "85331", "30028", "17584", "12345", "34983", "48503", "934399", "17088", "94874", "93893", "23939", "34989", "79843", "34398", "03438", "93843", "34893", "43893", "90834", "93439", "17876"];

let zipFetches = zips.map(zip => fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + zip + "&key=" + GoogleAPIKEY + "")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => data.results[0].address_components));

Promise.all(zipFetches).then((coordResults) => {
  console.log(coordResults);
});
```